# Generate Animated GIF with GM in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

so i've been tackling this one for a few days and got the point when i'm ready to ask for help.

I'm trying to generate an animated gif with in a node.js based app, using the [graphicsmagic](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#imagemagick) package.

I've generated several slides that look kinda like that

```
var slides = [];

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  var slide = gm(200, 200, '#000000')
    .fill('#ffffff')
    .drawText("Slide #"+ i);

  slides.push(slide);
}
```

I can convert them either into streams or buffers, i can save them as individual files on the hard drive and kinda works

But my problem is how to make an animated gif from those slides completely *in memory, without* saving the individual files on a hard drive?

I see `gm` has methods like `#delay()` and `#page()` and so technically i could craft a command like

```
convert -delay 200 -page slide1.gif -page slide2.gif output.gif
```

I just don't know how. I'm thinking it should looks something like that

```
var end_image = gm(200, 200, '#000000');

end_image.delay(500);

for (var i=0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
    end_image.page(200, 200, ????);
  });
}

end_image.write("output.gif");
```

basically I don't know how to convert a buffer into an argument for `gm`

Have anyone done it before? Maybe there is another way?

PS: i tried to use the `gifencoder` package as well, and successfully fed the `gm` buffers as frames into a gifencoder's API, but the output was all broken.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have tried both gifencoder (got as far as it sounds like you did, but get a segmentation fault on trying to use addFrame() with buffers) and the gif module (which seems to only work with older versions of node).

Comment: @Gregir nope, did it through dumping a bunch of files in `/tmp` and shelling out

Comment: I have the code to do this with the JIMP library but i am trying to figure out how to do this with GM myself

Answer (score 4):

This may not be exactly the answer you were looking for, but I think the following does answer the question title: "how to generate an animated gif with GM in Node.js"

```
var Gm = require("gm");

Gm()
.in("image1.jpg")
.in("image2.jpg")
.delay(100)
.resize(600,600)
.write("animated.gif", function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("animated.gif created");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my day.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [gif](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-gif) module lets you create static and animated gifs which may help you.

Comment: yeah, i saw it, but as far as i understand it works with hard drive, it dumps everything in the `/tmp` folder. i need to process everything _in memory_ so i could host say on heroku and have no HDD io. (i'll need to generate a lot of those images and i don't want to save them on HDD)

Comment: You should be able to do it in-memory also. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-gif/blob/master/tests/animated-gif/animated-gif.js).

Comment: @Nikolay, You have local file system available to use on Heroku, and it's perfectly fine to write temporary files. You just can't rely on them being there across app restarts.

Comment: @rane, yup that's what i did, i just thought maybe there is a way to make it work completely in memory

Comment: Also worth noting that node-gif only works on node <= 0.8, so it's quite outdated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a JavaScript encoder (as opposed to a C++ Node module), [gifencoder](https://github.com/eugeneware/gifencoder) seems to be able to do the job. An example from their page:

```
const GIFEncoder = require('gifencoder');
const encoder = new GIFEncoder(854, 480);
const pngFileStream = require('png-file-stream');
const fs = require('fs');

const stream = pngFileStream('test/**/frame?.png')
  .pipe(encoder.createWriteStream({ repeat: -1, delay: 500, quality: 10 }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myanimated.gif'));

stream.on('finish', function () {
  // Process generated GIF
});

// Alternately, you can wrap the "finish" event in a Promise
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  stream.on('finish', resolve);
  stream.on('error', reject);
});
```

Comment: Great. Any way  possible - instead of writing the gif to a file, pass it back as a response?

Comment: Instead of `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myanimated.gif'))` it is going to be something like `.pipe(response);` or maybe `response.body`. Ask a new question with details.

Comment: Thank you - Sure, there is a question. Can you please answer this question I've asked please? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823352/can-nodejs-gifencoder-directly-pipe-a-generated-gif-to-aws-lambda-response?noredirect=1#comment128628152_72823352