# Can nodejs gifencoder directly pipe a generated gif to aws lambda response?

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda

I am developing  a gif timer using node + express + [gifencoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifencoder) which will be hosted in AWS lambda, proxied via API Gateway. The examples in gifencoder are using locafile system, which is not ideal for lambdas. I've had this done in Java and worked pretty well. All i had to do was convert the generated gif to base64 encoded and set reponse type to image/gif.

But no idea how this can be done in node/gifencoder. Any pointers will be highly appreciated. I am pretty new to node (literally started an hour ago - have decent experience in javascript though).

Comment: Yes, it's even simpler. Just replace the `fs.createWriteStream()` with `res` because the `res` argument is already a writable stream

Comment: I don't believe JS lambda functions have a writable stream as it deals in `string` body responses... but how does an express app integrate with lambda? Lambda and express provide the same functionality of a HTTP interface to execute the JS function/handler code.

Comment: @kickyblue Unless I am missing some "run express in lambda setup",  the Java approach of base64 encode the data from gifencoder - `encoder.out.getData()` and return it as the body from the lambda function should work

Comment: This thread seems relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6uy4ph/does_lambda_support_nodejs_streams/. To my eyes it reads as though you can use Node streams withing the implementation of your lambda handler (there is an example of streaming into an S3 file), but you cannot stream into or out of your lambda. I have not found anything more "official" confirming or denying the Stream API support in the Node Lambda runtime.

Comment: Thank you. You don’t need to to stream, in lambda I use api gateway as a proxy and what I did with java was converted the image binary as a base64 string and wrote into the response and adding the header as a gif. I’ll be surprised if it won’t be possible in NodeJS. Gonna try tomorrow and will pos back here. I am nee to NodeJS but got plenty of us experience. So shouldn’t be too difficult I guess.